# What are the best/simplest classes used for WRITING files in Java?

Tags: java, file, file-io

Was anything introduced in Java, in the last editions (1.5/1.6) that facilitate writing strings to files (the Scanner of writing)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Easier](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/WriteToFile.html) than FileWriter?

Comment: It will do. And it seems to be the most widely used. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a core library in Java but [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html) in Apache Common IO is a useful class.

```
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(File file, String data );
```

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use [`PrintStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) and [`printf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, I don't imagine what the "Scanner for writing" would be - I don't see a duality there. For simple writing of text, a Writer seems enough.

If you are thinking of something like a formatter, there are good third party libraries, for example, I like [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I find I use RandomAccessFile a lot.

```
RandomAccessFile rafWrite = new RandomAccessFile("<file name>", "<mode, usually rw>");
rafWrite.writeBytes("<text you want to write>");
```